# Can someone help me sort my AWS EBS volumes using boto3?

Tags: python, sorting, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

This code works if I just list out the volumes but when try to sort by volume size I get an error "TypeError: 'ec2.Volume' object does not support indexing". The commented section is what I used to sort the volumes. I am hoping to sort by id then size. Thank you

```
from operator import itemgetter
import boto3
import sys

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
vol_array = ec2.volumes.all()

#for v in sorted(vol_array, key=itemgetter(0)):
for v in vol_array:
    a = v.id
    b = v.state
    c = v.size
    print('{}   {}  {}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 1):

That error means you're trying to use `obj[0]` on an object that doesn't support it. For example:

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass

>>> a = A()
>>> a[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    A()[0]
TypeError: 'A' object does not support indexing
>>>
```

Specifically in your code that happens because you're using `itemgetter(0)` which translates to `v[0]` which is not supported.

You should write a proper function that returns the keys you want to sort on without using `[0]`. For example:

```
def my_sort_key(v):
  return v.id, v.size

for v in sorted(vol_array, key=my_sort_key):
  print(v.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `attrgetter('id')` instead of `itemgetter(0)`.

```
from operator imprort attrgetter
sorted(vol_array, key=attrgetter('id'))

[ec2.Volume(id='vol-01a954af'),
 ec2.Volume(id='vol-029234fa'),
 ec2.Volume(id='vol-047156e0')
...
```

Comment: Thank you both. These comments are very helpful.